# For all $x,y\in G$, there exists $z\in G$ such that $y=xz$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I found the following problem:

- For all $x,y\in G$, where $G$ is a group, there exists $z\in G$ such that $y=xz$.

I tried to answer it in the following way: Multiply the equation by $x^{-1}$, then we have: $y=xz \implies x^{-1}y=z$ and then, the proposition becomes:

- For all $x,y\in G$, multiplying $x^{-1}$ (which always exists, by the definition of group) by $y$ always produces an element $z\in G$.

Which is true because groups are closed by the operation on them. Is that correct?

Comment: Is $G$ a group here?

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Comment: @KentaS Yes. Sorry, I corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the promise of the closure axiom is that anytime you apply the group operation to two elements of $G$, you get another element of $G$. By the inverse axiom you have inferred the existence of the element $x^{-1}$. You are now free to construct the element $x^{-1} y = x^{-1}xz$ to conclude that $z= x^{-1}y$.